# How to copy event via CTRL + Drag & Drop in FullCalendar v4?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

This example of copying events doesn't work in FullCalendar v4:
 https://codepen.io/ally-murray/details/JBdaBV
Does anyone know how to make this functionality in the current version?
Function "renderEvent" doesn't exist:

```
$calendar.fullCalendar(
      "renderEvent",
      {
        resourceId,
        title: droppedEvent.title,
        start: startDate,
        end: endDate },
      true);
```

Comment: See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3 and then https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent

Comment: P.S. please don't ask the same question repeatedly. I already made a similar comment on your earlier one. You can reply to that if you didn't solve the problem yet. Also you can edit your existing question, which will put it higher up the list for people to see. Asking the same question repeatedly is not the right way to use the site. Thanks. [How to copy event via CTRL + Drag&Drop in FullCalendar v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747863/how-to-copy-event-via-ctrl-dragdrop-in-fullcalendar-v4)